# How to upgrade 12.04.2 kernel and HWE to raring?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, kernel, 13.04

As the topic states I want to upgrade my 12.04.2 to newest raring lts kernel and HWE.

Now I have:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS
Release:        12.04
Codename:       precise

Linux NAS 3.5.0-28-generic #48~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 24 21:42:24 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Some history:
Originally installed 12.04.1 LTS, then upgraded to 12.04.2, and some time ago I've upgraded kernel and HWE to quantal by installing:

```
linux-generic-lts-quantal and xserver-xorg-lts-quantal
```

Now I'd like to the same but to raring. And there lies the problem, as linux-generic-lts-raring exists but xserver-xorg-lts-raring does not. Did the procedure change, or I'll have to wait a bit for xserver to show up in the repos ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `xserver-xorg-lts-raring` package was on `proposed` repository for a while, but I just checked again and it's now available on `main`. I have only the regular repositories enabled (no `proposed` nor `backports`) and was able to install it alongside `linux-generic-lts-raring` and it's running fine on my system.

Comment: I'm trying to do it, but after installing linux-generic-lts-raring and a restart I can't install xserver-xorg-lts-raring because of these conficts: xserver-xorg-lts-raring:
 W konflikcie z: libgl1-mesa-glx (>= 0~)
 W konflikcie z: libgl1-mesa-glx (>= 0~)
 W konflikcie z: libglapi-mesa (>= 0~)
 W konflikcie z: libglapi-mesa (>= 0~)

Comment: I've managed to install it after manually remove conflicting packages (and a whole lot of other packages). Did anyone had problems with mdadm RAID5 after upgrading kernels to lts-raring ? Mine droped out one disk (no disk errors in logs - SMART is clean)

Answer (score 2):

According to the Ubuntu X team's [R-series LTS backport](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/r-lts-backport) page,

> The official hardware enablement stack will be officially released as part of the 12.04.3 update.

And according to the [Precise Pangolin Release Schedule](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseSchedule), this will happen on 15 August 2013.

The upgrade policy around this is shown under the [Kernel/LTSEnablementStack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) page.

Comment: So... Is it safe for now to just upgrade the kernel to lts-raring ?

Comment: I don't know. Ask on IRC and find out? :-)