# Does btrfs support per user quota?

Tags: btrfs, quota

If I move the /home/... folders to a btrfs partition, can I still enable per user quota? That is, each user should be able to use a limited amount of storage.

Answer (score 4):

> Does btrfs support per user quota?

No, it doesn't.

> If I move the /home/... folders to a btrfs partition, can I still enable per user quota? That is, each user should be able to use a limited amount of storage.

Yes, the trick is to use a subvolume for each home.

Btrfs supports subvolume quotas [since Linux Kernel 3.6](http://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_3.6#head-ea3fff8d6256386209140642c82c229f4fb22b25).

([Note that](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=linux-image-generic) Ubuntu Precise has 3.2, Quantal has 3.5, Raring has 3.8, and note that you can [install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/296307) the Raring [Hardware Enablement Stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) on Precise, to have an updated kernel.)

Instructions to enable quotas are in the Btrfs FAQ, "[How do we implement quota in BTRFS?](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/UseCases#How_do_we_implement_quota_in_BTRFS.3F)". Subvolumes created after `btrfs quota enable` support quotas automatically. Subvolumes created before `btrfs quota enable` need manual intervention to support quotas.

1. Mount the btrfs filesystem
2. Enable quota: `btrfs quota enable mountpoint`
3. (If the filesystem already contains subvolumes, enable their quota support:)

   - List the subvolume IDs with `btrfs subvolume list`. The number that follows `ID` (at the beginning of each line) is the subvolume's id.
   - Create a qgroup with `btrfs qgroup create 0/subvolume-id path-to-subvolume` (don't forget to replace the `subvolume-id` with the correct id)
   - Rescan the subvolumes, since the quota settings have been changed: `btrfs quota rescan`
4. Create new subvolumes that you need: `btrfs subvolume create mountpoint/subvolume-name`
5. Limit the subvolume usage: `btrfs qgroup limit 100G path-to-subvolume`
6. Profit.

Finally, set up `/etc/fstab` to mount the subvolumes automatically at boot:

> UUID=uuid-of-the-filesystem /home/mountpoint btrfs defaults,subvolid=subvolume-id 0 0

Alternatively, you may use `LABEL=label` or `/dev/sdxn` to refer to the btrfs filesystem.

To apply the changes to `fstab` without rebooting: `mount -a`

Answer (score 1):

No, Btrfs doesn't support user quota, It supports directory quota. So you can add quota for each user directory, but if you have shared directory with multiple users/groups then you can't set/count space for every user separately.

So you can't limit userX to be able to put 1MB of files in `/home/shared` and another userY to be able to put 10MB of files in the same `/home/shared` folder. But you can set different limits for `/home/userX` and `/home/userY`.

This is not user quota, but *sub-volume quota*. You can put multiple sub-volumes in single limit (for example user have `/home/userX/` and `/backups/userX/` then both can be under single limit.